# Failing to compactmap an array of documents from Cloud Firestore query snapshot

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I assigned a listener to a collection to receive updated filtered list of that documents yet it's failing to compact maps document to an array of the original type .

To explain more here is the code:

```swift
  if let user = FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().currentUser{
    let requestsRef = db.collection("requestInfo")
    let query = requestsRef.whereField("userId", isEqualTo: user.uid)
    query.getDocuments(){(querySnapshot, error) in
      if let err = error {
        print(err.localizedDescription)
      }
      else {
        let documents = querySnapshot?.documents
        self.requests = documents!.compactMap{document in
          let request = try! document.data(as: RequestInfo.self)
                    
          print(request?.carModel)
          print(self.requests)
          return request
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I receive the documents correctly and it is decoded correctly. I can see in the console the `carModel` being printed yet the `requests` array is empty, so it's no use.

Any idea why is that?

Comment: Where do you see it's empty, whil it's not elsewhere? Async issue?

Comment: theres a list that is updated based on this array named requests , its empty . and the print gives me the info in car model where as the request should be appended to requests  , its not .

Comment: This code doesn't add a snapshot listener, it just gets the documents (a one-time deal). Instead of `getDocuments` you need `addSnapshotListener`.

Comment: The `self.requests` property will only be set once you return from the closure, so the print statement *inside* the closure (`print(self.requests)` will always print the state *before* the closure finishes. You mentioned you're assigning the result to a `List` view - it'd be helpful to provide us with more context and show us your view as well, and how it is connected to the code you've shown above.